# Как с помощью Сокетов Java подключиться к другу?

Tags: java, сокет, клиент-сервер

P.S. Хочу с помощью Сокетов Java подключиться к другу.

Как я подсоединяюсь к Серверу (например, к [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)) находящемуся в интернете и как он соединяется со мной, если мой ип динамический? Как он меня находит? Как он мне отправляет информацию? Значит, если он (сервер) может подключиться ко мне, то и я, имея динамический IP, могу подключиться к другу, у которого тоже IP динамический, зная как это делает сервер. Как он это делает?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[@Сергей Пестов](/users/2982/%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2), в двух словах, процесс обычно протекает немного по другому, чем Вы представляете.

У сервера есть статический IP (например 8.8.8.8) и он слушает порт (например 8888). У вас IP динамический (скажем, сейчас 10.1.2.100), а вот у Вашего роутера - статический (допустим 178.10.20.30) во внешней сети и 10.1.2.1 во внутренней (на другом сетевом интерфейсе (с ним Вы физически связаны)).

Когда Ваш клиент говорит connect(), то сокет получает от ОС адрес (хост:порт), например  10.1.2.100:1234. Ваша ОС пишет его в интерфейс, который связан с роутером (с MAC адресом *роутера*). Роутер переправляет пакет запроса на адрес 8.8.8.8:8888, но *меняет адрес отправителя* на 178.10.20.30:10234 (он меняет номер порта (берет "свободный" в данный момент)) и *запоминает*, что адресу 10.1.2.100:1234 на внутреннем интерфейсе соответствует 178.10.20.30:10234 на внешнем.

Таким образом сервер 8.8.8.8:8888 будет получать пакеты от 178.10.20.30:10234 и отправлять свои **ответы** на этот адрес. Роутер, получив пакет, находит адрес получателя (Вас) в своей таблице NAT (Network Address Translation) и переправляет Вам пакет, но уже  по адресу (меняет в заголовке пакета) 10.1.2.100:1234.

В общих чертах длжно быть понятно.

Comment: Спасибо большое, Просветили. Долго разбирался в вашем ответе, но понял.

Comment: Можно ещё вопрос: Если только у меня будет статический ИП, то сможем ли общаться с другом. Если я правильно понял ответ, то получается, что подключиться ко мне сможет только он, а я подключусь к нему после того как он подключиться ко мне, зная его ардресс на Роутере. Так?

Comment: Connect не на статический IP в Вашем случае не пройдет. *Client* подключается, устанвливается соединение, далее обмен пакетами идет "по проторенной дорожке". 

Вы не сможете соединиться (сделать connect() со стороны сервера) еще раз (по адресу, который увидели в пакете клиента) т.к. сокет клиента *не слушает* соединений. Т.е. пакет на соединение может и дойдет через роутер (если предыдущее соединение еще не закрыто), но ОС клиента отбросит его.

Comment: Возник вопрос по теме. Что если на компе этого друга tcp-listener слушает соединение? Слушает он, например, по адресу 10.20.30.40:8787, у роутера свой адрес (скажем, 178.179.180.150). Так вот, как мне к "другу" подключиться? 

Здесь нужен (кажется это так называется) проброс портов, верно?

Comment: Да. В инете много материала на эту тему. Например, [вот](http://dlink.ru/ru/faq/246/1156.html).